# Implementing Application Insight to Azure Function App

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

Anyone know of any god guide for this?

First i created an Application Insight Resource and put:

```
APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY = "INSTRUMENTATION KEY"
```

in the Function Apps Application Settings.

I have tried implementering the nuget package for the funtion app like this.

Createing a project.json file and pasting this:

```
 {   
  "frameworks": {   
   "net46":{   
    "dependencies": {   
     "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights": "2.1.0"   
    }   
   }   
   }   
 }
```

It installed the nuget package (i could see it in the log, everything went well).

After that i put these snippets in my code to use the *telemetry.TrackException(exception)* functionality:

First...

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
```

Then:

```
var telemetry = new TelemetryClient(new TelemetryConfiguration("INSTRUMENTATION KEY"));
```

and in my catch:

```
telemetry.TrackException(e);
```

and when i try to save my Function app i get this error:

> error CS1729: 'TelemetryConfiguration' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Exceptions should be sent to AppInsights automatically once you enable Application Insights integration via the portal.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use reference the Application Insights library to use it with Functions. If you've already set the `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY` application setting, you can simply add the `ILogger` interface as a parameter to your function and it will automatically send the log data to your Application Insights instance.

Full documentation can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring

Comment: ok, well you're right about that, everything seems to logg automatically, but the ting is my exceptions are logged as messages not as exceptions. How do i solve this? Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: That I'm not sure about. It might be worth opening a bug so the product team can take a look at making these errors and not informational messages: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues

Answer (score 0):

Addition to @ChrisGillum answer for .Net Core 3.1 Azure Function:

If you create a new Azure Function with `Http trigger` from Visual Studio the following line will exist in the example:

```
log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
```

Add `"APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"` to `local.settings.json` `Values`.

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "<YOUR_GUID>"
  },
}
```

Note that the key must be in an app setting named `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY` and nothing else.

Logging is then added automatically:

[image]

Complete guide for hosted values:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring?tabs=cmd#enable-application-insights-integration